# Interview Q - Design File System - Review

Tags: filesystems

All,

I was recently asked in one of the technical interviews to write a high level design for a File Sysem. My answer to the question was as follows. I would request everyone to please review and let me know if there are suggestions/improvement:

```
  interface BaseFileSystem
{
    /*Basic file/folder attributes are:
      1. File/Folder Size
      2. File/Folder Date created
      3. File/Folder Date Modified
      4. File/Folder permissions - Read, write and execute
      5. File/Folder Owner - Owner of the file who defines permissions for other users
      6. File/Folder Visibility - Hidden or Visible
      7. File/Folder Name 

      Hence each one of the above attributes would have public <return type> get() and public void set<AttributeName>(<variable datatype>) */
}

public class File implements BaseFileSystem
{
       /*The `File` class should implement all of the methods from interface `BaseFilesystem`.
         In addition, it must also implement following specific methods that can only be associated with physical files*/

        public String getFileExtension(){….}

        public void setFileExtension(String value) {….}

        public String[] getAssociatedPrograms(){ …..}

        public void executable(){ …. };
}

public class Folder implements BaseFileSystem
{

      /*The `Folder` class should implement all of the methods from interface `BaseFileSystem`. In addition, it must also implement following specific methods that can only be associated with the physical 'folders'*/

        public BaseFileSystem[] getSubFoldersAndFiles(){ …. }

        public void addSubFolderAndFiles(BaseFileSystem fileObj) { …. }

        public void executable(){throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
}
```

Additionally, any general pointers to such design questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three essential operations, that are missing:

- reading the contents of a file
- writing the contents of a file
- testing whether a `BaseFileSystem` is a `File` or a `Folder`

On the other hand, there are some operations that I do not consider essential for a file system:

- the file extension does not have any significance in all operating systems. Then why should a method exists for setting and retrieving it?
- the associated programs only have a meaning in a single computer/os combination. In a general purpose file system, the programms might exists only temporarily (because a different os is booted or the device is moved). It should IMHO not be stored as part of the meta information of a file, because of separation of concerns.
- `public void executable()` seems out of place. But this is only a guess, because I do not know what this method is supposed to do. If this executes an executable file: that should be done by the operating system manually. Also, it has no business being defined in class Folder.

Furthermore, the attributes that you defined in `BaseFileSystem` make some assumptions about the requirements of the file system. Maybe your simple permissions system is not sufficient or the purpose of the file system and ACLs are needed. Maybe visibility is determined by the name of the file (like in UNIX). You should clarify that beforehand.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `read` and `write` were the basic functionalities I have missed in my solution. Regarding the programs associated with file extensions, why do you think that it should not be a part of file system? In the sense, where do you see that logic fitting? If I have a file with n programs associated with it, I think it is that file responsible to tell the O.S which programs the O.S can use to read the data in the file.

Comment: As Oswald said, user A can associate the file with program X, user B with program Y. Moreover, in most operating systems you do not associate programs with a particular file, but with a particular type of files (determined by file extension, some attribute of the file or whatever).

Comment: does there need to be "path" on BaseFileSystem or Folder?

Answer (score 1):

From what i know about interview questions, you need to make sure you ask clarifying questions about the file system. The hidden part of a question like that is to make sure you're someone who can identify ambiguity. Also figure out who your users might be, since they might not care about "Date Modified"

When i read this question, i was thinking something *nix-based and would use the command lines! Good luck!

Comment: Well I had to submit the answer electronically. So I had to assumed some of the functionalities and there was never a chance of back and forth discussion. Hence I have asked it here ! Thanks for the reply

Comment: I am sorry but I disagree with you about "Date Modified" functionality. Above all, this code is not UI based and hence I am not sure why I would need to understand the audience. I would do that when designing the UI and not the file system.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not sayign Date Modified should be left out. My main highlight was to make sure you asked clarifying  questions =]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense to just give an API. If you follow POSIX, the API is already given to you. Wouldn't it make more sense to describe the data model for the file system? For example, how do you link the data, track used/free blocks, handle modifications, etc...

I didn't like this either:

> Hence each one of the above attributes would have public  get() and public void set() */

I really detest getters/setters. If I was going to design a file system, I would push any file metadata outside of the file system. Instead provide a generic interface for arbitrary metadata. For example, permissions might be irrelevant on an embedded system, so why make it part of the file system?

Good luck!